# Universal Render Pipeline Not Working At All

Tags: unity-game-engine, render

I am using unity 2020.3.19f1 with URP 10.6.0 and I have the URP asset file in my assets folder, I have also added it under Renderer in the Project Settings tab, and the Graphics Quality too, I have created the scriptable 2D renderer Data file and added that to my URP Asset file but the textures in the game neither turned pink nor went black, as they used to when I used this renderer previously. Also I have tried "Upgrade Materials to URP materials" and it doesn't seem to do anything. Does someone have a solution?

Comment: When it went black, did you set up a 2d light?

Comment: it didn't go black, that's what concerns me, previously on other projects it used to, and I followed the same steps, now it just stays the same.